# Is this description of "universal systems" with regards to Deconstruction valid?

Tags: logic, metaphysics, derrida, deconstruction

**EDIT : I have accepted an answer for the time being**

I have accepted an answer to this question. The answer and subsequent comments exchange has given me some more insight into my question. It does not, however, answer it from the perspective of formal logic. I am still curious about this aspect of my question. Stated more directly: How could Derrida's argument (or the interpretation of it given in the quoted passage below) be analyzed in terms of a logical system?

Ultimately, I am trying to understand why this kind of thinking was so vehemently opposed by Searle and others and would be interested in a response from a different methodology and discipline than Poststructuralism itself.

---

Since I am unfamiliar with Postmodern philosophy I have been reading [Deconstruction: A Reader](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0415936888). In the introduction the author makes a claim that I find to be somewhat dubious. He states the following:

> Consider the following universal system:
>   [image: Universal system]
>
> Imagine a system in which all the system of the world (A to Z) are related. In order for this system to be a system (for it to be systematic) it must be closed. A to Z must be related in clear and predictable ways in order for their relation to be systematic and this means that there must be a discernible limit to the action of the system. Therefore the system must be closed. So, let us call this system of system the universal system and its aim is to relate all known system to one another. There are two consequences from this description. First, if there is indeed a limit to the action of the system, something must exist outside the system. Whenever we draw a limit we are defining what is inside the limit by presupposing an outside of the limit. Thus, if there is something outside the limit of the universal system (and it must have a limit in order to be a system) then the system cannot be 'universal' because it leaves 'something' unaccounted for. Secondly, what is it that the universal system does not account for? Which system lies outside the closed field of systematic relations described by the 'universal system'? The answer is the system itself. The universal system cannot account for itself as a system. To do so would be to recognize the impossibility of maintaing the limit to the universal system and so to admit that it is neither systematic nor univeral. In this way the universal system, far from regulating all systems, would have to admit that no system can be truly systematic because it is not possible to maintain the rigorous purity of a limit. The universal system demonstrates the impossibility of the system *per se*, and so undoes the logic of a 'properly' maintained inside and outside.

It would seem to me the author is trying to state that a universal system, by definition, has to exclude something in order to maintain its completeness. But why? If it is a universal system (a set of all sets?) then why must there be a "discernible limit to the action of the system". And if the system "is closed" how can this be the case? If the system is universal then it includes everything there is to include.

Further it seems the author's usage of the words limit is more like a boundaries between two zones (the system and not the system) rather than actual limit. So yes, "something must exist outside the system" and "whenever we draw a limit we are defining what is inside the limit by presupposing an outside of the limit". But if this is actually true then by what right do we have to call this system of systems a universal system in the first place?

Furthermore, why can the universal system not account for itself? If this is the missing piece (Derrida's "supplement") then it seems the author is implying that what lies beyond the limits of the universal system is itself. This make no sense to me. In fact, this appears to be a paradox.

It seems to me that the author is making some kind of informal reference to Godel's Incompletness Theorem. I do not have the proper background in the mathematics behind this (or formal logic for that matter) but as I understood it, Godel's theorem applies to the arithmetic portion of axiomatic systems. How does that apply in this case?

And the bigger problem to me is that how does any of this extend to discussions on sociology, language, consciousness, and so forth? Ultimately, the author is going to use this logic to define the relationship between many different kinds of systems (social, political, scientific etc) and do not see how this is possible given the description above.

**I would be most interested in a response that answers this question from the perspective of formal logic.**

Comment: I would recommend reading Derrida's "Structure, Sign, and Play in the Discourse of the Human Sciences." What this author says is related to what Derrida says there, but Derrida describes himself much differently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know Derrida better than I know formal logic, but i'll do my best to incorporate that perspective.

What I think this author leaves unmentioned, which is most important to understanding this configuration Derrida's thought, is the concept of a system's center, as it is called in ["Structure, Sign, and Play in the Discourse of the Human Sciences"](http://www.mariabuszek.com/kcai/PoMoSeminar/Readings/DrrdaSSP.pdf), or the transcendental signified as it is called in *Of Grammatology*. The center is not simply an important piece of a system, and it would be difficult to illustrate its relations in a diagram like the one above. The center grounds the systematicity of the system, which is to say that it is the reason the system holds together as a unified whole and is intelligible as a single entity.

The paradox (Derrida would say the *aporia*) of the center is that it must be both inside a system (at the center, no less) and beyond it, transcending it in order to ground it. To use a topological or architectural metaphor, what grounds a structure must be outside of it or independent of it in order to offer support (think of the earth in relation to a building) yet it must have a point of contact and that force must suffuse and sustain the entire structure.

There are several examples of how a center of the universal system has been imagined, and all of them reveal this same aporia. It has been common since the Enlightenment to imagine that natural causality could be the guiding force of all reality, determining everything from the motion of planets to the motion of atoms, and dictating consciousness through the activity of the brain. But such explanations leave a necessary gap in their accounting of the universal system. If everything in nature has a cause, then the universe itself, in order to be natural and subject to the absolutism of this explanation must have a cause. What could have caused it? Its cause must be outside of the universe. This aporia shows the simultaneous immanence and transcendence of the center, or the notion of a limit having an outside, as the author you mentioned described it.

Many thinkers portrayed God as a solution to this aporia, by causing all natural existence, and being causa sui, or cause of Herself in turn. But this only displaces the problem, as the entire history of mysticism and theology attests in its different configurations of the immanence and transcendence of God. (Immanuel Kant in the *Critique of Pure Reason* showed how both scientific thought and religious thought face this same aporia in attempting to grasp universality.)

With respect to logic, as your question asked, it would be necessary to ask the question of the ground of logic. That is, what makes logic a system? What makes it true? What makes it applicable universally? Universal and necessary truth is intrinsic to the idea of logical systematicity, and the Principle of Sufficient Reason (itself a fundamental logical principle) insists that everything true have a sufficient reason why it is true. As you probably know, the Empiricist tradition attempted to ground logic in experience - we learn of syllogistic reasoning and other basic logical principles through seeing that they work every time we try them. But Hume and Kant pointed out that this is faulty logic because logical truth is accompanied by the conviction of its universality and necessity, and these two traits could never be learned from finite experience.

Ultimately, another aporia faces logic at its roots. If it were grounded empirically, either learned through the senses or written somehow in our psychology or the gray matter of our brains, then it would be impossible to account for its universality or necessity. If these principles are eternal, static entities or Ideas, like immobile Gods, it is unclear how they ever enter reality - how do we ever become conscious of them and how do they come to shape phenomena in the world? To fully elaborate this aporia it is necessary to consider the metaphysical notion of a first principle as it was articulated most powerfully by Aristotle and Hegel. The principle cannot be static but must both explain and be the cause of all the individual change and motion which exists.

Comment: There's a lot to unpack here. I'll start with a few of my first questions. 1. Why can't the universe itself be its own support? Why _must_ there be something outside? What reason do I have to believe that this is not the case? You touch on this in your explanation but can you expand? 2. With regards to logic are you suggesting that all logical systems are built upon assumptions (axioms) which the structures rest but that these axioms themselves cannot themselves be proven without referring to other axioms (thus forming an aporia?).

Comment: 1. Think of the idea of a universe which is it's own support as a displacement of the problematics which come from having a God who is causa sui as the ground of all existence. Part of what Derrida's thought brings out is that this structure of aporia repeats itself no matter how philosophical discourses attempt to configure themselves or rearrange their elements. To understand how empirical thought confronts an aporia, think of Kant's description of the antinomy of causality - either the chain of natural causes is infinite, or there is a first cause...

Comment: ...if the chain of causes is infinite, this fails to satisfy the demands of reason - how could something exist without having a beginning? how could it be without first coming to be? But a first cause is no greater satisfaction to the demands of reason. If we choose something which is part of this universe, than it is a natural thing and by definition must have a cause. This is why the universe cannot ground itself, as you say - really that is a contradiction in terms, like saying that something is caused and causeless, because that natural things have a cause is a priori...

Comment: ...if you choose something outside the universe, like God, then it is not necessary to claim that it must be caused, but we can never have any evidence that such a thing in fact exists, precisely because it is beyond any possible perception. This is what Kant calls the antinomy of reason as it relates to the category of relation (which includes causality), and what Derrida would call aporia.

Comment: 2. What you mention here is one possible way of identifying an aporia in logic, but not the one I had in mind. It's interesting, though - notice how the same structure of foundations repeats itself here - in order to answer the charge that logic cannot ground itself, logicians identify a principle which would be causa sui - the principle of contradiction, which is supposedly presupposed by any thought or statement. 

What I had in mind depends most on the concept of a fundamental discourse or what Aristotle called First Philosophy. In order for a discourse to be posited as fundamental...

Comment: It must be the cause of everything that is - it must be both what causes it to exist, and what allows it to be known. Philosophers who argue that logic can attain this status tend to point out that it grounds all other discourses - no science can exist (whether it is mathematical, empirical, or humanistic) without presupposing the principles of logic, which are what makes it a discourse in the first place - a body of grounded conclusions that nowhere contradicts itself (supposedly, according to this ideal of science and of logic). But a first philosophy should do more than this. it should...

Comment: ...be not only the uppermost principle of our knowledge but also the cause of what it allows to be known. How could a static set of logical principles accomplish this? If we treated logic as fundamental in this way, than the fact that anything ever changes is a violent intrusion on our static world, inexplicable according to our fundamental principles. This is another sense in which logic as a total system presents an aporia.

Comment: 1. This seems to be a version of the cosmological argument. Does Derrida (or others) confront the idea of what caused the first cause? This argument also raises the question of how we can any degrees of certainty at all. It seems to me you are saying that any attempt to structure something is itself based on uncertain terms with relations to some other grounding which is itself subject to the same uncertainty. So can there be no objective certainty about anything at all?

Comment: Further it seems that all knowledge is rooted in the limit between known and unknown and all knowns are thus grounded by unknowns until those unknowns become known. I am thinking mostly of Bataille’s usage of nonknowledge here if you are familiar. Is this an equivalent comparison?

Comment: 2. The biggest problem I have is that this kind of thinking has to make an appeal to the laws of logic in order to support its own view. You said 'that is a contradiction in terms' and have also used logical reasoning to undermine the assumptions of logical reasoning. It seems to me that this leads to an aporia, infinitely regressing on itself and forming the same problem that it is attempting to criticize. I am not even sure how to approach this problem since the very argument you are making is undoing itself, thus repeating the structure of the aporia.

Comment: Derrida's thinking absolutely depends on logic, and he frequently emphasizes the fact. In the first words of an interview called "A Taste for the Secret" he says: "there is an injunction to the system i have never renounced...deconstruction, without being anti-systematic, is on the contrary, and nevertheless, not only a search for, but itself a consequence of, the fact that the system is impossible...it often consists...in making appear - in each alleged system....a limit in the totalization, a limit in the movement of syllogistic synthesis."

Comment: In other words, it is by obeying with the utmost rigor the demands of logical, philosophical (onto*logic*al, as he says) thought, that deconstruction reaches its inevitable aporias. People who defend the fundamental coherence of logic point out that the denial of logic contradicts itself. Derrida would agree, and would add only that the confirmation of logic contradicts itself as well. this is the aporia precisely.

Comment: Your comments have been helpful in clarifying the passage I cited. Additionally, the Derrida lecture you linked to made things much more clear to me. I would like to discuss this further but that would take a lot of your time. If you would like to move this to chat at any point and continue the discussion there I would be up for that. I have accepted your answer to my question.

Comment: sure thing @syntonicC - there used to be a link to move conversations to chat but im not seeing it here - if you can start the chat id be glad to discuss more with you there.

Comment: also - if you're interested in the relationship of derrida and searle I highly recommend Limited Inc a b c... which includes the lecture "signature, event, context" in which derrida discusses JL Austin and speech act theory, a summary of searle's response (i believe he didnt want his work included in the volume) and a long reply from derrida. This is most substantive debate derrida has carried on with an analytic philosopher.